# I can't use tr() in Qt 5.5 outside the Qt classes

Tags: c++, qt, tr

I'm a little beginner, and I've a problem with implementation of the tr function in Qt. If I'm using tr("string") outside the Qt classes I'm getting errors.
I found information, that I should use QObject:: before the tr(), but If I try to do it with

```
temp += QObject::tr("Example"); // temp is std::string
```

I'm getting error

```
C2679: binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'QString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Another example:

```
    QString filename="example.txt";
    QFile log(QDir::currentPath() + "//" + filename);
    if ( log.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text) )
    {
    QTextStream plik( &log );
    plik.setCodec("UTF-8");
    (...)
    plik << QString::fromUtf8(QObject::tr("Example2")); // Error
    }
```

I'm getting error

```
C2665: 'QString::fromUtf8' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt has so many accessors and [QString::toStdString()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString) as well.

```
temp += QObject::tr("Example").toStdString(); // temp is std::string
```

for the stream need to convert either to Utf8 byte array:

```
plik << QObject::tr("Example2").toUtf8(); // fixed
```

or even better it [accepts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-4) QString as well.

```
plik << QObject::tr("Example2"); // will do
```

Comment: C2660: 'QString::toUtf8' : function does not take 1 arguments Is there another fix?

Comment: Fixed the first case.

Comment: Ok, it works - thanks. But what about the first error of my question? I have 20 errors like it...